# How can I avoid entering my password for everything?

Tags: password

Its getting really annoying having to use my password for everything from opening my internet browser, to doing anything in the terminal, to installing any sort of software etc. Is there a way to disable this? I feel like everytime I sneeze I need to put in my password first. I tried changing it to nothing and then to another variation of my password to make it easier to use (since I'm putting it in all the time) and now some programs/actions require the older password and some require the new one. Its really confusing and its making everything a hassle. Is there a way to disable this or even just make it to where I know for sure which password it wants me to use?

Thanks for any future responses. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: "for everything from opening my internet browser, to doing anything in the terminal" Hope you are not really using sudo or something with graphical software.

Comment: You should add the steps you took to change your password.

Comment: It sounds odd, that you need super-user privileges to run a web browser or access the internet. That doesn't sound like the default configuration. Are you sure, you configured your system correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to enter your password for everything. Either your installation is severely broken somehow, or (more likely) you're not using it correctly.

Consider running `ls` in the terminal. You don't need your password for this. Do you always run it as `sudo ls`? Don't do this. If running `ls` without sudo fails, paste the result of running `sudo ls -l /bin/ls` here.

Answer (score 0):

Linux and other UNIX-like operating systems handle permissions very tightly. If you launch applications from your terminal constantly, you can switch your permissions to superuser with this command: `sudo su` Note that this shouldn't be used as a be-all-end-all command. Software launched with root permissions can alter your system without asking for additional permissions. Don't launch your web browser as superuser, for example.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser

Comment: Clarification - `without asking for your permission` - By being root you have given permissions, either by being logged in as root or by entering your password if you had to `sudo`.